# Formula to reference a cell value that contains text and retain the cell refences formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a bunch of cells containing text.  The text in those cells have multiple font sizes and styles.  I need to replicated those cells in a different order further down the worksheet and if I make changes to the original cells I need the cells that source from the original cells to carry the changes including the formatting.  I know I can do this one cell at a time but surely there is a better way?

EG
Original Cells

A1: **Boot** - *Lace Up, Steel Cap*

A2: **Shoe** - *Velco, Blue*

A3: **Socks** - *Knee high, Black*

Cells below

A301: =A1, formatted exactly the same as A1

A302: =A3, formatted exactly the same as A3

etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would require vba.  Worksheet functions cannot by their nature change the formatting of cells.

Comment: @Scott is right. I'd suggest copying the formatting by hand and then do the rearranging

Answer (score 0):

So what you are really looking for is conditional formatting (Or so it seems)

Here's a snippet from Microsoft of how that happens.  See below for the example or for the full example see the link below.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

> [image]
>
> BlockquoteCreate conditional formatting rules with formula
>
> For example, let’s say you track your dental patients’ birthdays to see whose >is coming up and then mark them as having received a Happy Birthday greeting from you.
>
> In this worksheet, we see the information we want by using conditional formatting, driven by two rules that each contain a formula. The first rule, in column A, formats future birthdays, and the rule in column C formats cells as soon as “Y” is entered, indicating that the birthday greeting has been sent.
>
> Sample conditional formatting in Excel
>
> To create the first rule:
>
> Select cells A2 through A7. Do this by dragging from A2 to A7.
>
> Then, click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule.
>
> In the New Formatting Rule dialog box, click Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
>
> Under Format values where this formula is true, type the formula: =A2>TODAY()
>
> The formula uses the TODAY function to see if the dates in column A are greater than today (in the future). If so, the cells are formatted.
>
> Click Format.
>
> In the Color box, select Red. In the Font Style box, select Bold.
>
> Click OK until the dialog boxes are closed.
>
> The formatting is applied to column A.
>
> To create the second rule:
>
> Select cells C2 through C7.
>
> Repeat steps 2 through 4 above, and enter this formula: =C2="Y"
>
> The formula tests to see if the cells in column C contain “Y” (the quotation marks around the Y tell Excel that this is text). If so, the cells are formatted.
>
> In the Color box, select White. In the Font Style box, select Bold.
>
> Click the Fill tab and select Green.
>
> The formatting is applied to column C.

Comment: No, thanks for your help but I am not after conditional formatting.  I want to mirror the multiple text formats in a single nominated cell. And do this with many other cells.  If I change a source cell I want the destination cell to update the value (which is text) and the multiple formats (eg font sizes and styles) of the text contained in the source sell..